# How to add series lines to 100% stacked bar charts with plotly

Tags: python, plotly

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-series-lines-drop-lines-high-low-lines-or-up-down-bars-in-a-chart-29139b09-ce6a-49ad-95e4-447562a22260
In Excel, I want to use the lines connecting the bar charts labeled "Series lines" in the plotly bar chart.
Is there a way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a Plotly analog to what PowerPoint calls "stacked lines"  https://i.stack.imgur.com/napdO.png