# Stack series in Plotly.js line chart

Tags: javascript, plotly, linechart, stacked-chart, plotly.js

Is there an option in Plotly.js to stack line series (series `"type": ""`)?  In the example below the three lines to sum to 100%.
[image]

It is possible to show series  as either stacked (e.g. "barmode":"stack") or side-by-side (e.g. `"barmode": "group"`) when they are shown as bars (series `"type": "bar"`), as below.  That doesn't seem to work for lines.

CodePen:  https://codepen.io/__proto__/pen/OJwOeWv

[image]

[How to add series lines to 100% stacked bar charts with plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71491201/how-to-add-series-lines-to-100-stacked-bar-charts-with-plotly)

PowerPoint has a similar feature to show lines stacked or not

[image: PowerPoint has a similar feature]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the traces to be stacked by assigning them to a [`stackgroup`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#scatter-stackgroup) :

> Set several scatter traces (on the same subplot) to the same
> stackgroup in order to add their y values (or their x values if
> `orientation` is "h"). If blank or omitted this trace will not be
> stacked. Stacking also turns `fill` on by default and sets the default `mode`
> to "lines" irrespective of point count.

And use [`groupnorm`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#scatter-groupnorm) to normalize the sum of the stackgroup as a percentage : `groupnorm: 'percent'`.

Now, since "*stacking turns `fill` on by default and sets the default `mode` to "lines" irrespective of point count*", Plotly will draw a ***stacked area*** chart by default, with no marker, ie. :

[image: stacked area chart]

So you will need to be explicit in order to obtain ***stacked lines** with **markers***, that is, by setting `fill: 'none'` and `mode: 'lines+markers'` to each trace.

You might also need to explicitly set the yaxis `rangemode` so that the yaxis range always extends to zero regardless of the input data (as it is the case above when fill is enabled).

In the end you should obtain stacked lines :

[image: stacked lines chart]

Here the code used for the example above :

```js
var traces = [{
  x: [1,2,3], 
  y: [2,1,4], 
  stackgroup: 0, 
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  fill: 'none',
  groupnorm: 'percent' // nb. only the 1st groupnorm found in the group is used
}, {
  x: [1,2,3], 
  y: [1,1,2], 
  stackgroup: 0,
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  fill: 'none'
}, {
  x: [1,2,3], 
  y: [3,0,2], 
  stackgroup: 0,
  mode: 'lines+markers',  
  fill: 'none'
}];

let layout = {
  title: 'Normalized Stacked Lines',
  yaxis: { rangemode: 'tozero' } 
  width: 600,
};

Plotly.newPlot('plot', traces, );
```